# How to capture detected face image using MLKit firebase FaceDetection

Tags: android, firebase, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, java-canvas

I want to only capture detected face image not whole image on camerasource.

I am drowing box like this

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Face face = mFace;
        if (face == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Draws a circle at the position of the detected face, with the face's track id below.
        float x = translateX(face.getPosition().x + face.getWidth() / 2);
        float y = translateY(face.getPosition().y + face.getHeight() / 2);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, FACE_POSITION_RADIUS, mFacePositionPaint);
        canvas.drawText("id: " + mFaceId, x + ID_X_OFFSET, y + ID_Y_OFFSET, mIdPaint);
        canvas.drawText("happiness: " + String.format("%.2f", face.getIsSmilingProbability()), x - ID_X_OFFSET, y - ID_Y_OFFSET, mIdPaint);
        canvas.drawText("right eye: " + String.format("%.2f", face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability()), x + ID_X_OFFSET * 2, y + ID_Y_OFFSET * 2, mIdPaint);
        canvas.drawText("left eye: " + String.format("%.2f", face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability()), x - ID_X_OFFSET*2, y - ID_Y_OFFSET*2, mIdPaint);

        // Draws a bounding box around the face.
        float xOffset = scaleX(face.getWidth() / 2.0f);
        float yOffset = scaleY(face.getHeight() / 2.0f);
        float left = x - xOffset;
        float top = y - yOffset;
        float right = x + xOffset;
        float bottom = y + yOffset;


        this.faceTrackingCords.y = top;
        this.faceTrackingCords.width = right;
        this.faceTrackingCords.x = left-right;
        this.faceTrackingCords.height = bottom;


        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mBoxPaint);
    }
```

and trying to capture image like this but cropped image is not as expected.

```
                mCameraSource.takePicture(null, new CameraSource.PictureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                        Bitmap bitmapCropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,(int)faceTrackingCords.x, (int)faceTrackingCords.y,
                                (int)faceTrackingCords.width, (int)faceTrackingCords.height);
                        screenImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapCropped);
                    }
                });
```

Kindly please help

Comment: Are the face coordinates from the same image you captured? Should use the same image for face detection and crop.

Comment: I am doing this but it is not cropping as expected it is cropping somewhere else in the image.                                                                                                           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

               ``` Bitmap bitmapCropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,(int)myFace.getPosition().x, (int) myFace.getPosition().y,
                        (int)myFace.getWidth(), (int)myFace.getHeight());
                screenImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapCropped);```

Comment: The size of the picture taken and the size of the preview image used by detector can be different. You will need to check the size of the picture taken and the preview size then apply the scale factor and then crop.